# index=False not working due to which not able to use range in skiprow function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on pandas and trying to read a CSV located on my desktop. I actually need the following rows to be published in the defined data frame.
Rows as per CSV = `[15,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24]` but as soon as I try to define a range to skip in pandas I start getting NaN Values in my output

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\Tradition_Basis_RFR_2021_12_05_15_00_00.csv', header=0, skiprows=1, nrows=22)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Bid', 'Ask'])
df['Mid_value'] = df['Bid']/2 + df['Ask']/2
print(df)
```

Script:

[image: script screenshot]

Output:

[image: output screenshot]

CSV file:

[image: csv file screenshot]

When I only use `skiprows=1`, in the output I only need red highlighted rows in dataframe:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: could you give me the csv file? are you sure they are 'comma' seperated?

Comment: @FatemehSangin : sure, please let me know where can i share it ?

Comment: Upload it on dropbox, then create a sharable link and add it to your post. So that everyone can download your data and you'll receive answers more quickly.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8ae91933ud4sdx/Tradition_Basis_RFR_2021_12_05_15_00_00.csv?dl=0

Comment: Are you done? Was the answer helpful?

Comment: yes @FatemehSangin i had one more doubt but dont this is the right platform for a long end discussion

Comment: actually was trying to join one more data frame using a different csv, but dataframe2 is giving some trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code please:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Tradition_Basis_RFR_2021_12_05_15_00_00.csv", header=0, skiprows=1, nrows=22)
data = data.drop(columns=["0"])
data['Mid_value'] = data['Bid']/2 + data['Ask']/2
```

which correctly results in data to be like:

```
    Name    Date    Time    Bid     Ask     Mid_value
0   PLNAB6W2Y   03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.2000  3.2400  3.2200
1   PLNAB6W3Y   03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.1900  3.2300  3.2100
2   PLNAB6W4Y   03 DEC 2021     17:56   3.1700  3.2100  3.1900
3   PLNAB6W5Y   03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.1550  3.1950  3.1750
4   PLNAB6W6Y   03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.1175  3.1575  3.1375
5   PLNAB6W7Y   03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.0800  3.1200  3.1000
6   PLNAB6W8Y   03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.0500  3.0900  3.0700
7   PLNAB6W9Y   03 DEC 2021     17:56   3.0350  3.0750  3.0550
8   PLNAB6W10Y  03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.0400  3.0800  3.0600
9   PLNAB6W12Y  03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.1200  3.1600  3.1400
10  PLNAB6W15Y  03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.2900  3.3300  3.3100
11  PLNAB6W20Y  03 DEC 2021     17:54   3.3900  3.4300  3.4100
12  RUB1YIRS    03 DEC 2021     17:00   9.9200  10.0200     9.9700
13  RUB2YIRS    03 DEC 2021     17:00   9.4900  9.5900  9.5400
14  RUB3YIRS    03 DEC 2021     17:00   9.1900  9.2900  9.2400
15  RUB4YIRS    03 DEC 2021     17:00   8.9900  9.0900  9.0400
16  RUB5YIRS    03 DEC 2021     17:00   8.8500  8.9500  8.9000
17  RUB6YIRS    03 DEC 2021     17:00   8.7700  8.8700  8.8200
18  RUB7YIRS    03 DEC 2021     17:00   8.7200  8.8200  8.7700
19  RUB8YIRS    03 DEC 2021     17:00   8.7000  8.8000  8.7500
20  RUB9YIRS    03 DEC 2021     17:00   8.7000  8.8000  8.7500
21  RUB10YIRS   03 DEC 2021     17:00   8.7100  8.8100  8.7600
```

Then all you need to do is either`loc` or `iloc`:

```
data = data.iloc[12:17, :].append(data.iloc[18:, :])
data = data.drop(columns = ['Date', 'Time'])
```

which results:

```
    Name    Bid     Ask     Mid_value
12  RUB1YIRS    9.92    10.02   9.97
13  RUB2YIRS    9.49    9.59    9.54
14  RUB3YIRS    9.19    9.29    9.24
15  RUB4YIRS    8.99    9.09    9.04
16  RUB5YIRS    8.85    8.95    8.90
18  RUB7YIRS    8.72    8.82    8.77
19  RUB8YIRS    8.70    8.80    8.75
20  RUB9YIRS    8.70    8.80    8.75
21  RUB10YIRS   8.71    8.81    8.76
```

Comment: data1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\atul.sanwal\\Desktop\\BGC_RUB_2021_12_05_15_00_00.csv', header=0, skiprows=1, nrows=111)

data1 = data1.drop(columns=["0"])
data1['Mid_value'] = data1['C']/2 + data1['D']/2
data1 = data1.iloc[97:98, :].append(data1.iloc[105:, :])
data1 = data1.drop(data1.columns[1, 3, 5], axis=1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(df1)

Comment: I can not code you here. Add another post and ask there. You can moreover mention me there.